# Essbase Smart View error: Invalid free form

Tags: excel, hyperion, essbase

When I connect to my `Essbase` cube from `Smart View` I get an "invalid free form" error. Any help will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its a bug. We have to restructure clear the data and  our outline and cl